# Input text retornando bool(false)

Tags: php, html

Tenho esse código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML> 
    <HEAD>
     <TITLE>Cadastro</TITLE>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </HEAD>   
    <BODY>
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="teste.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pesNome" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pesNome" placeholder="Nome">
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Gravar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

E esse código PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<?php
        $nome=isset($_POST['pesNome']);
        var_dump($nome);
?>
<a href="index.php">voltar</a>
</html>
```

Minha intenção é que o `var_dump` retornasse o que foi digitado no input **pesNome**, mas ao invés disso me retorna a mensagem `bool(false)`.
Alguém sabe me explicar o motivo ?

Comment: Eu sei. Você está fazendo `$nome=isset($_POST['pesNome']);`, então o valor de `$nome` será o retorno de `isset`, que verifica se determinado valor existe. E lembre-se de definir o atributo `name` nos campos do formulário.

Comment: O input `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pesNome" id="pesNome" placeholder="Nome">` retornar o valor é pelo name do input
`$nome=$_POST['pesNome'];`

Comment: Obrigado, o problema na verdade era o atributo name.
O isset eu tinha colocado na verdade como um teste depois que joguei o post e me retornou um erro de que não existia o pesNome.
Eu pensava que o post pegava o nome no id.
Valeu!!!

Answer (score 3):

O [**isset**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) é um valor **[booleano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booleano)**. Logo você está atribuindo à variável `$nome` um valor booleano (*true* ou *false*).

O correto é atribuir á variável o valor do $_POST:

```
$nome = $_POST['pesNome'];
```

E depois verificar se a variável foi *alimentada*:

```
if( isset($nome) ){
    // $nome tem algum valor
}else{
    // $nome não tem valor algum
}
```

Comment: Na verdade você precisa verificar o `isset` antes da atribuição, pois, dependendo das configurações do servidor, isso resultará em erro quando o valor não existir.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Confesso que nunca vi um exemplo disso. Geralmente se vê nesta ordem. Se for depender das configurações do servidor, seria um caso peculiar.

Comment: Pior que não é particular, não. E basta analisar pela lógica: atribuir um valor que pode nem existir? Isso não faz sentido. Alguns fazem assim, de forma errada, pela falsa sensação de segurança gerada pelas configurações padrões da maioria dos servidores de suprir qualquer mensagem de erro ou alerta. O ideal ainda é utilizar o `filter_input` e verificar se o resultado não é falso: `$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pesNome')`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ahhh... se não existe ele eh vazio rs.. dá na mesma. Gostaria de um exemplo pra eu testar aqui no servidor. Se passar eu apago a resposta rs. Mas é interessante sua observação. Não sabia.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mas acho que já vi isso `$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pesNome')` em algum lugar